# Is it possible to catch signalR connection disconnect event? Error: Connection disconnected with error webSocket closed with status code: 1006

Tags: websocket, signalr

I'm using signalR v.1.1.2 https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR#readme (yes, pretty outdated)
I've successfully initialized and started signalR connection.
After a few minutes, connection drops and i got this annoying, hesitant error logged in the console, triggered from signalR's internal libraries.

`Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ()'`

My aim is catch this error w/ proper event listener and reconnect immediately or notify user w/ retry connection modal popup. I just cant catch signalr close event. Am i missing sth?

I'm so desperate that i wrote like 20 methods to catch this, but none of them worked for me. I'm sure these methods are bound to connection entity that i set up and run. Btw signalR documentation page about connection lifecycles, dont work for me either https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#how-to-notify-the-user-about-disconnections

Any help or advice is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

None of these work:

````
  console.log("disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.connectionSlow((resp) => {
  console.log("connectionSlow inline cb")
})

connection.onclose((resp) => {
  console.log("onclose inline cb")
})

connection.close((resp) => {
  console.log("close inline cb")
})

connection.on('Disconnected', (resp) => {
  console.log("camelCase Disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.on('ConnectionSlow', (resp) => {
  console.log("camelCase ConnectionSlow inline cb")
})

connection.on('OnClose', (resp) => {
  console.log("camelCase OnClose inline cb")
})

connection.on('Close', (resp) => {
  console.log("camelCase Close inline cb")
})

connection.on('disconnected', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase Disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.on('connectionSlow', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase ConnectionSlow inline cb")
})

connection.on('connectionslow', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase 2 Connectionslow inline cb")
})

connection.on('close', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase close inline cb")
})

connection.on('onClose', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase OnClose inline cb")
})

connection.on('onclose', (resp) => {
  console.log("lowercase 2 Onclose inline cb")
})

connection.connection.disconnected((resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.connection.onclose((resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection onclose inline cb")
})

connection.connection.connectionSlow((resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection connectionSlow inline cb")
})

connection.connection.close((resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection close inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('close', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection lowercase close cb")
})

connection.connection.on('Close', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection camelcase close cb")
})

connection.connection.on('disconnected', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('onclose', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection onclose inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('onClose', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection lowercase onclose inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('connectionSlow', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection lowercase connectionSlow inline cb")
})
connection.connection.on('connectionslow', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection lowercase2 connectionSlow inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('Disconnected', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection camelCase disconnected inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('OnClose', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection camelCase onclose inline cb")
})

connection.connection.on('ConnectionSlow', (resp) => {
  console.log("connection.connection camelCase connectionSlow inline cb")
})```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a couple of hours, we've resolved our issue. 
What we did was to bind "close, disconnect..." events with `.on` syntax proper to the documentation.
 However what worked for us, is explicitly declaring `.onclose` event bounded to connectionHub's connection object so that this function is successfully triggered on error, via signalR internal http connection library.

```
connection.connection.onclose = (error) => {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend you come up to at least v2.x. This may be part in why that newer documentation is not helping you.

You can see my answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395315/best-practices-for-reconnecting-a-disconnected-signalr-client-js/45415631#45415631).

Essentially that will let you catch a disconnect event, pop up a modal if you wish (you will have to code that) and then reconnect after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @frank-m but for some limitations i cant update the library to v.2 atm