# How to find typescript signalR's onDisconnect method

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I have an Angular client which uses signalR library `"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4"`

I need it just to receive notifications from ASP.net server. So I build and start hubConnection which is
`private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;` and then subscribe on different messages from server

```
this.hubConnection.on("SomeMessage", (data: MyDto) =>
  myActions()
);
```

All works fine and receives messages but after several hours of work something happens (with network I suppose) and on server fires method

```
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
```

That is fine, but I want to handle disconnections on client's side. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101053/how-to-determine-server-disconnection-from-signalr-client) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395315/best-practices-for-reconnecting-a-disconnected-signalr-client-js) and many more answers but my `hubConnection`  has neiter `disconnect` method nor `hub` property which are mentioned in those answers. So I would appreciate any hints where they could be. Preferable in typescript, not in html.

**UPDATED**

Well, as was proposed I changed signalR package to `"@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.4"` by I still can't find `onDisconnect` event

There is an instance of `signalR.HubConnection` which I build as shown below

```
  private buildConnection(url: string, token: string) {
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(url, { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
      .build();
  }
```

But this instance does not have onDisconnect event.

Comment: Try using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) package. The one you are using is older, and deprecated.

Comment: What about `hubConnection.onclose`?

Comment: @NathanFoss It works if I totally close asp.net service. Left it work, let's see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented, upgrade to the newer version, which now has an event for OnDisconnect and a way to access the reason in the client.

SignalR 2.1 adds an overload to the server OnDisconnect event that indicates if the client deliberately disconnected rather than timing out. The StopCalled parameter is true if the client explicitly closed the connection. In JavaScript, if a server error led the client to disconnect, the error information will be passed to the client as $.connection.hub.lastError.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    if ($.connection.hub.lastError) 
        { alert("Disconnected. Reason: " +  $.connection.hub.lastError.message); }
});
```

Reference Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#detecting-the-reason-for-a-disconnection